Having trouble with super()
I have two single inheritance classes, intended as a simple tree implementation:
class tree:
    def __init__(self, nodes = set()):
        self.nodes = nodes

    def addnode(self, node):
        self.nodes.add(node)

class Node(tree):
    def __init__(self, name = '1', data = None, children = set()):
        self.data = data
        self.children = children
        self.name = name
    
        super().addnode(self)

tree()
Node('1')

However, running this code returns an error:
    self.nodes.add(node)
    ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'nodes'

I couldn't find any resources that answer this specific question. can someone help me?

class tree:
    def __init__(self, nodes=None):
        if nodes is None:
            nodes = set()
        self.nodes = nodes

    def addnode(self, node):
        self.nodes.add(node)


class Node(tree):
    def __init__(self, name='1', data=None, children=None):
        super().__init__()
        if children is None:
            children = set()
        self.data = data
        self.children = children
        self.name = name

        super().addnode(self)


tree()
Node('1')

You need to initialize the parent class to be able to use it.
for more information look at: What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().__init__() and explicit superclass __init__()

why are you using super().addnode???
